# Getting "Channel (TC)" Data from Adobe Analytics (Omniture) API with Python

Tags: python, adobe-analytics

Is there any way to grab the data that's in the Channel (TC) reports? It doesn't seem to be directly linked to any of the elements that are available via the API.

These are the ones I'm referring to:

Natural Search
Paid Search
Referring Site
Email
Affiliate
Shopping Engine
Social Media
Ad Network (Retargeting)
Uncategorized
Ad Network

I'm using this python wrapper:

https://github.com/dancingcactus/python-omniture

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like Marketing Channels, and an admin renamed them to Channel (TC):

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mchannel/c_getting_started_mchannel.html

The friendly names to these variables are:

- First Touch Channel
- First Touch Channel Detail
- Last Touch Channel
- Last Touch Channel Detail

The backend column names are:

- va_finder_id
- va_finder_detail
- va_closer_id
- va_closer_detail

Details on the backend columns names are found here: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/datafeeds-reference.html

Comment: I agree with your hunch about renaming the marketing channel, but I believe OP is using the Analytics/Reports API, not the data feed. Possible elements can be found here: https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/reporting-api/elements.md  , specifically `firsttouchchannel`,`firsttouchchanneldetail`,`lasttouchchannel`,`lasttouchchanneldetail`